# How to disable "Security Alert" window in Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, https, browser, certificate

I'm using Webbrowser control to login to HTTPS site with "untrusted certificate".
but I get popup such standart window "Security Alert" about untrusted certificate:

[image: Security Alert window]

I have to find this window by title and send it <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to press *Yes*:

```
int iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, "Security Alert");
NativeWin32.SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("Y%");
```

but user can see a flickering of this window.

How can I ignore this alert?
Or disable this "untrusted certificate" check in Webbrowser control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebBrowser control - ignore SSL errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933254/webbrowser-control-ignore-ssl-errors)

Comment: See also: SSL errors in WebBrowser controls for console apps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698002/ignoring-web-browser-ssl-security-alerts-in-console-application/21008529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
```

Obviously, blindingly allowing certificates is a security risk.  Be careful.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the WebBrowser control. It may be just me, but I suspect this solution isn't applicable as the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control isn't sending requests via .NET.

Comment: @DanielBallinger It's not just you. I am having the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12999735/1357272).

Comment: This is for managed objects ONLY. Webbrowser control is a wrapped unmanaged control. This is why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate isn't from a trusted certifying authority (the first point in the prompt) then you could install the certificate under the Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the PCs in question.

You can do this under View Certificate.

In some ways this could be a simpler solution as it doesn't require any code changes that accept any and all certificates. It does however require the certificate to be installed wherever the application is used.

Comment: Looks like a great idea, but I just tried it and [it didn't work for me](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12999735/1357272) for some reason. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Here,we go with the solution:
I run it on the Browser_Navigated event as the underlying activeX component is null until then.

**Ref:**https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f686de1-8884-4a8d-8ec5-ae4eff8ce6db/new-wpf-webbrowser-how-do-i-suppress-script-errors?forum=wpf

```
         private void Browser_Navigating_1(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
        HideScriptErrors(Browser,true);

        }

    public void HideScriptErrors(WebBrowser wb, bool Hide)
    {

        FieldInfo fiComWebBrowser = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (fiComWebBrowser == null) return;
        object objComWebBrowser = fiComWebBrowser.GetValue(wb);

        if (objComWebBrowser == null) return;

        objComWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, objComWebBrowser, new object[] { Hide });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I set the WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed property to false, I do not get these popups anymore

Comment: This will hide it. It will not click YES

Comment: are you sure about this ? my code has been running for a few months now without issues

Comment: Yes it will only hide it so the page will fail to load in the OP case

Answer (score -1):

[I see this solution.it work for me.It very easy way.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/04/side-effects-of-setting-the-silent-scripterrorssuppressed-property-for-web-browser-control.aspx)