# I am trying to consume data from the Avaya office manager API. CertificateValidationCallback causing error

Tags: c#, api, webforms

My error is 
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
I am using the example code from the Avaya office management api documentation.
I can't get CertificateValidationCallback to compile.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
    System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback); 
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String url = "https://10.207.251.41:7070/WebManagement/ws/sdk/security/authenticate";
    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("X-User-Client", "Avaya-WebAdmin");
    request.Headers.Add("X-User-Agent", "Avaya-SDKUser");
    String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
    String responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

    response.Close();


}
```

Comment: Sounds like the certificate is fake/self-signed. There's a magic variable you can set that ignores certificate errors, but folks will scowl if I share that non-production-quality information :P

Comment: get your callback working; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5043083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the certificate is not trusted by Certification Authority (and I don't think so because of the request, but it sounds instead like a test certificate), you shall install it on your system as trusted by MMC console, adding "certificate" snap/in, selecting your local pc as destination. Then, in the snap in shall appear a list of certificate folders, find the "trusted root certificates" and import the certificate (if you don't have it, I think that you can download it with the browser visiting the link https://10.207.255.45:7070 ). Once it's installed there, this could fix your problem