# .NET webbrowser security prompt

Tags: c#, winforms, automation, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I am using a .NET web browse control for windows forms.
Every time I visit this specific web page, I get this specific prompt:
http://screensnapr.com/v/fS15lG.png

This nag box disrupts the program flow.
Ive tried the accepted answer from this post:
[How to disable "Security Alert" window in Webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178578/how-to-disable-security-alert-window-in-webbrowser-control)
But it did nothing to stop the prompt.

Is there a way to disable it through code.

Comment: FYI, you are not using a C# WebBrowser Control. You are using the .NET Windows Forms Web Browser Control.

Answer (score 1):

Not that i know of, the issue is some of your content is served over https and some over http, change the urls of the items in your page to start with `https://` or better yet change them to `//<domain>/path/to/item.ext` note the omission of `http:` or `https:` so that the resources are requested over whatever transport you have connected with.

Comment: It changes to https whenever I set it to http, i have no choice.

Comment: make sure all your resources (images/CSS/JS) are prefixed with // instead of http://

Answer (score 0):

It is a secure zone setting that you can override via installing your own [IInternetSecurityManager implementation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246227). [MSHTML calls the QueryInterface method on the IOleClientSite interface to get the IServiceProvider interface in order to query your IInternetSecurityManager implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537182%28VS.85%29.aspx), which means you need derive from System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite in order to add an IServiceProvider implementation.