# Display html containing iFrame in Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

i am creating a window application as well as a web application using c#. Scenario is like below:
1. Admin will post messages using Wysiwyg editor( i am using tinyMCE) from the website 
2. User will have windows form that will be download the  message and display it on the form.

I have taken a [webBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28VS.85%29.aspx) control to display it. its working fine to display html( formatted text along with picture). problem  occurs when we want to display video on it.

I am using following code for that:
 webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");

```
            HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            doc.Write(String.Empty);
            string strHTML="&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com/embed/xXdDjnVM1kI&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;425&quot; height=&quot;350&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #ff0000; font-size: xx-large;&quot;&gt;Hi, &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #33cccc; font-size: large;&quot;&gt;Enjoy Ganganam Style&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;";
            string strDecoded=System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(strHTML);             
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = strDecoded;
```

Its showing me security alert while running it:
[image: Error message]

When i add these sites in the trusted site, it works fine. but i want to get ride of these security warning. for that i have tried `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`, but its not working also. and also tried [How to programmatically answer "Yes" to WebBrowser control security alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999735/how-to-programmatically-answer-yes-to-webbrowser-control-security-alert). 

When `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` then iFrame come like below:
[image: error]
But i have Adobe Flash Player, and i can play the video by adding the warning site in the trusted sites manually.

Is there any option to avoid these and play the video? any kind of help and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you are developing this on windows server? Is it going to be deployed on windows server?

Comment: @Antarr Byrd, yes you are correct. i am developing it on Windows Server 2008 R2. it will run on the server machine as well as xp and window 7 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by [disabling enhanced security](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chenley/archive/2011/03/10/how-to-turn-off-ie-esc.aspx) or by adding the page to the [trusted zone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#programmatic).

Comment: is there any way to find the site name which are coming to popup?

Comment: Looking at the popup you posted it appears to be youtube.com

Comment: after clicking yes, it comes with another popup with application.exe vhost