# .NET WebBrowser Control in WindowForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm currently using a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` in my program. When I try to access some websites over https, the message "There is a problem with your websites security certificate" appears. Is there any way I can get WebBrowser to ignore these types of warnings?

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301127/how-to-ignore-a-certificate-error-with-c-sharp-2-0-webclient-without-the-certi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141303/display-html-containing-iframe-in-windows-form-c-sharp#comment19582540_14141303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
  (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

But that does leave the client vulnerable (i.e. cannot verify the server's identity).

A better approach would be to implement a method that actually validates the certificate, or if the certificate cannot be validated presents the user with a choice whether they should proceed or not.