# How to allow untrusted SSL in the WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, ssl

I'm doing a very small app that has to display some web page(like a "kiosk"). Some of the pages that I've are only accessible in HTTPS but don't have a valid SSL certificate.

Is there a way to force the WPF `WebBrowser` control to allow any SSL certificate?

Something like:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser helpers:WebBrowserUtility.BindableSource="{Binding UrlToDisplay}" AllowInvalidSSL="true"></WebBrowser>
</Grid>
```

If not, can you think to an alternative?

Comment: Have you tried to reconfigure system settings? I am not sure you can control this setting control-by-control, have you tried to reconfigure this on OS level?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178578/how-to-disable-security-alert-window-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: `WebBrowser` is very thin wrapper around native controls, so you will have hard time trying to modify this behavior on WebBrowser control level. In any case - just fix the problem instead of searching for workarounds. For example install target certificate to local machine to make it trusted.

Comment: @vasek: No, since the goal is to be able to publish this without having to manage things on the environment side.

Comment: @Evk: I know but it's not an option. Or at least if something should be done(like install target certificate) this should be done by the application.

Comment: @VladimirArustamian I don't have a popup to close or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can solve it with WPF WebBrowser. However, if you use [CefSharp.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/) you can easily implement `IRequestHandler` and view untrusted sites without user being noticed.

```
bool IRequestHandler.OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
{
    if (!callback.IsDisposed)
    {
        using (callback)
        {
            callback.Continue(true);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Taken from [this example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/RequestHandler.cs#L30). Works perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm fully open to CefSharp.Wpf. Trying it now. How do you specify which `IRequestHandler` to use?

Comment: and more, how can you implement only this method?

Comment: @J4N You can't implement only this method, however if you just copy-paste the example above, you achieve desired funcionality. You attach the handler with `web.RequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler();` where `web` is `<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="web" />` in XAML. I've tested that and it works perfectly.